# How to delete SharePoint created client id and client secret

Tags: sharepoint

How can I find and delete created client id and secret created using https:///_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx or https:///sites//_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So any application which is registered using AppRegNew page is actually registered as an enterprise application in AAD. In order to completely remove the registered app you may do the following:

1. Double check and remove any permissions added for this app. You may do that by going to `<yourSite>/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx`page and just remove it from there
2. Go to the admin site of your tenant and to Azure AD and then to 'Enterprise Applications'. You may search for your app by given name (in my case it was 'test' or by generated ClientId)
   [image: List item]
   then just go to the properties of this app registration and delete it from there.
3. Now it takes about 30 days to completely remove your enterprise application from recycle bin AAD. So please be aware after you will remove it from AAD using UI (step 2) you will still get the app details when looking it up using `/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` page . But if you need to remove it completely and imidetly you may do it using `Remove-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject -Id <id>` command. Please follow the [instructions from this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/restore-application?pivots=aad-powershell) (the remove command is at the bottom)

I hope this will be of any help 
Cheers